# Joining OpenShift server to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, redhat, openshift-origin

Is it possible to make an OpenShift server a member computer of an Active Directory domain to enjoy the same AD services that a Windows Server would have?

Specifically, I am looking for integrated security, where a user with domain credentials logged in to a Asp.NET Core application on OpenShift would be similarly exposed in the `System.Security.Principal` object.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the member computers of an OpenShift cluster to an AD domain, but it won't get you what you seem to want. OpenShift, which is based on Kubernetes, runs apps in containers, (well, pods of containers) and the whole point is that they are carefully isolated from the host and from each other.